# "Pattern" name for premature modularization?

Tags: modularization

Is there an accepted name for what it's called when someone takes are relative small codebase and splits it up into many tiny libraries, containing just a few or even just a single class, or likewise splitting up a single coherent class into multiple smaller classes that depend on each other.

During my travels, I've twice come across projects that have been atomized in this way, where a single application contains 25+ tiny projects with a complex dependency graph, that all rolls into one application which compiles into less than a single MB of code while running on dedicated servers with hundreds of GB of storage available.

I am looking to discuss this pattern of coding with the other developers, but I am lacking knowledge about established vocabulary on this subject.

Can anyone suggest what this pattern (or anti-pattern) is called, and under which cases you may want to employ it, since I'm moderately certain that is has been employed to an extreme in the wrong context

**Edit:**
The core behaviour I'm investigating is the practice of migrating a coherent and single purpose codebase into multiple ultra-skinny library-projects with low-cohesion that are still tightly coupled with the rest of the original codebase.

While the code now compiles into an executable and 11 dlls, none of those dlls are possible to reuse independently. They have so many cross references that one of these libraries is just a collection of interfaces to break cyclic dependencies to allow the solution to compile at all.

**Second edit**
Promoted from a comment to one of the answers given:

I mean splitting, as in being moved to a separate project and compiled into a .dll file, in this case I have the main executable. This uses a class in .dll A, .dll A is implementing an interface that are defined in .dll B, as well as interacting with 2 other interfaces defined in B. The 2 other interfaces used, are defined in .dll file C and .dll file D, which in turn are also reliant on B. Neither A, B, C or D are used anywhere outside of the main executable, and there is no past, current or future requirement to be able to have multiple different implementations of A, C or D

Comment: [Microservice?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices)

Comment: See [What’s the right size for a Microservice?](https://kylegenebrown.medium.com/whats-the-right-size-for-a-microservice-bf1740370d47#:~:text=A%20Microservice%20should%20be%20%E2%80%9Csmall,to%20implement%20a%20Microservices%20architecture.)

Comment: These are not microservices though, heck, the first time I saw it was in 2007. This is more about taking the pieces of what might be a microservice initially and essentially atomizing them, turning them into the tiniest piece of code that can still compile, and sticking that into it's own little library. 

I'm looking at a project that contains a single class, that in turn just wraps 4 os-level calls. It comes with 2 interface references. Those interfaces are defined in a separate project that compiles into yet another library. Those interfaces are not implemented anywhere else.

Comment: Sounds like a flavor of [Premature Abstraction](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/386570/what-is-premature-abstraction) with a project twist.

Comment: I'd say that premature abstraction is adjacent to this. In my (sadly very real) example above, the wrapper class around OS calls makes sense to have in the code base. What doesn't make sense it to move it first out of the main project where it's used, and then moving the interface definition on top out into a different separate project, essentially scattering the code over a huge area.

Comment: I doubt there is a special name for it apart from "overengineering". Logical reasons might be a lead software engineer who hasn't learned the rule "know where to stop" from "The Pragmatic Programmer", or a too large team for a small task, and enough time to let [Conway's law] happen.

Comment: One of the best design questions to ask before letting new code into your code base is: “Why?”

Comment: It's called an Operating System.

Comment: @Grubsnik is it possible that they have moved out all knowledge of which OS the app is running on?  This would let them build a different OS adapter if someone ever got the code to run on a different OS.

Comment: By putting that code in a separate project they could easily remove the unneeded code when deploying.

Comment: Terminology for wrong-headed design generally doesn't exist except in the form of meme-like phrases which people invent off-the-cuff as a way of trying to neatly frame some kind of common misguided mindset  (For example the phrase *[Distributed Monolith](https://newrelic.com/blog/best-practices/distributed-monolith-vs-microservices)* is the kind of meme which conjures up all the pain of monoliths coupled with all the pain of microservice deployment for anyone who has ever had the misfortune of inheriting any such project)

Comment: If you want to explore the reasons why such designs ever exist in the first place then you're probably better off studying human psychology and how it affects business or project management, looking at the kinds of things which motivate people and lead them toward bad decision making.    Chances are that it's a combination of many different significant factors which are specific to a particular team or company  (e.g.  inexperience, naivety, group-think, developer ego, organisation culture, mismanagement, weak leadership, communication blunders, lack of discipline, etc.)

Comment: @BenCottrell My hope was that there was someone who had already coined a commonly accepted term for this, and possibly also scenarios where this might be a reasonable approach. I'm expecting this to be a case of a "Golden hammer" being applied, but I'm not sure where it is stemming from, before it got abused.

Comment: @Grubsnik Software Engineering doesn't really have much of its own terminology, most of the phrases you'll find are simply ordinary English Language words applied within a specific context and need clarifying by the people who use them.  You could likely find many terms to describe it, but if you try to use those terms in conversation with other developers they'll just stare blankly at you and either ask you to explain exactly what you mean or just try to guess and interpret for themselves.

Comment: @Grubsnik I'm disappointed you've chosen to ignore my question. I was hoping to gain some insight into their possible thinking. It's far easier to make a case against a design when you grasp their intent.

Comment: the phrase you are looking for is "YAGNI" you aint gona need it. But its rarely true

Comment: @Ewan BDUF is what YAGNI advocates would call this. Though that still says nothing particular about projects. If you’re going to be this vague you could also call it “Gold Plating”. That is: working on a project beyond the point of adding any real value.  That’s why I asked the question I did. If this project had real requirement that demanded this work it’s nothing to be sneered at. But if it did it doesn’t seem to have successful communicated that fact to the OP.

Comment: the OP could call it "making my code look bad"

Comment: @Ewan Pattern name or no, I think what the OP wants is a way to explain why this is a bad idea. Just need enough info from the OP to confirm that it is.

Comment: @candied_orange, sorry for leaving you in the dark for a bit. Weekend happened. In both the cases, it's been a single team of 1-3 people working on a small codebase with a well defined platform to run on, with no requirement to be able to support other platforms.

Comment: @Ewan I'm trying to understand the motivations behind this kind of behavior. At first glance this seems non-sensible. But I have come across this twice, in different teams, with developers from different countries, working in different companies, that are active in completely disparate businesses. The only common feature is that it is written in C#. So I'm trying to understand if this is some smart thing being applied in the wrong place, or it's a (somewhat) common anti-pattern. Or maybe it's something completely different?

Comment: on the face of it splitting the code out is best practice, so it unclear what your objection is. I know we all make pragmatic decisions on how much best practice to apply, but what criteria are you using to judge that decision here? To someone used to programming in that style it might have simply been the fastest way to produce the application. Or it could have been a bigger project that got abandoned or cut short, Or it might have had strict testing requirements, or they might have been following a company standard template for new projects.

Comment: @Ewan splitting out code into separate classes makes perfect sense. I'm talking about the meta-level, where they have moved individual classes into separate compiled libraries, none of which actually can be deployed independently of the bigger solution.

Comment: again, its best practice to separate stuff out. a "finished" library can be moved to a separate code repository and not touched. Theres no cost to separating out projects. what's your objection? just that you wouldnt have bothered?

Comment: @grubsnik Thank you for responding. Unfortunately by not updating the question you didn't get enough credit to keep the close voters at bay. We need objectively answerable questions for the votes to mean anything. Comments are meant to inspire edits. They shouldn't be where clarification lives. Pity, I was looking forward to answering.

Comment: @Ewan it isn't a "finished library" in any sense, it's a lot of singular low-cohesion classes each moved into separate solutions that cannot compile independently. By move the code out like this, it seriously damages readability, since neither codebase is possible to review and understand within its own context.

Comment: @candied_orange thanks for spelling out the obvious, I have edited the question, hope this helps clear things up a bit

Comment: @grubsnik I think it’s a good edit. But now we need two more reopen votes. Hard to do since the traffic has died down.

Comment: obviously at least one must compile independently. are they solutions or projects? to me this just seems like a case of a different judgement on how pragmatic it is to follow best practice on a small code base. If you objected to a class being split into two where both shared a single responsibility or no interfaces or something there would be a violation of solid or something more concrete

Comment: Enterprise Edition, see https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition

Answer (score 1):

What you describe could to be [traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)) or [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) based code.  These programming techniques try to promote maximal reusability  and tend to therefore compartmentalize code in very small modules.  Both techniques compose small classes/modules into larger ones using either an inheritance-like mechanisms or composition and inevitably result in complex dependency graphs.

There are family of problems where mixing and traits are very suitable, so it's not necessarily premature modularization.

(Of course, it may also be unrelated to these techniques and simply result of over engineering, or over-ambitions - there is no name for that as far as I know)

(P.S: I've eliminated [microservices](https://microservices.io) and [serverless architectures](https://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html) from the list of candidates: these use many small components to achieve a high scalability, but none of them is characterized by "*splitting a single coherent class into smaller classes*").

Comment: This makes some sense. At least it might point to what the original authors were imitating, even if the actual code doesn't have use of these. The bigger question for me is when they split out code into multiple smaller separately compiled libraries, that still are 100% dependent on the main library to compile and run, and where they are always deployed together still

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing. Modularity is a basic part of the design of any system and the coarseness of it is not likely to change during the development time. Because you should have a pretty good idea about how the system is going to be used upfront.

Modularity and distribution touches the usability directly, it is not just some technical detail that may be worked out and refined later without changing the system on a functional level. Modularization may be pointless, but if so there would be nothing premature about it. It would just be a poor choice.

The way the company is organized may also be an issue: if different people are responsible for different parts it makes sense to split up the application accordingly.

Comment: There is no conways law at work in these scenarios. it's been perpetuated by 1-3 person teams. Modularization could be done later on if you learn that parts of the code could be recycled in a different project if it was spun off as a separate module, but in both of these cases there is no other such projects planned.

Comment: @Grubsnik Personal preferences aside, what would you say to be the cost of splitting things up? If it might ever be useful and it is cheap, I don't see a reason to not do it.

Comment: Splitting things up that shouldn't be split means you get low cohesion and badly damages code readability, because a lot of the relevant logic is fragmented across a lot of tiny code snippets.

Comment: @Grubsnik No, mere splitting does not touch dependencies or cohesion at all. The parts will know each other and use each other just the same. Whether they are in different files and or classes does not change that. It would take a design change to do that, splitting is an implementation detail. You may still find it cumbersome to switch code files or scroll a bit but the model would not change.

Comment: I mean splitting, as in being moved to a separate project and compiled into a .dll file, in this case I have the main executable. This uses a class in .dll A, .dll A is implementing an interface that are defined in .dll B, as well as interacting with 2 other interfaces defined in B. The 2 other interfaces used, are defined in .dll file C and .dll file D, which in turn are also reliant on B. Neither A, B, C or D are used anywhere outside of the main executable, and there is no past, current or future requirement to be able to have multiple different implementations of A, C or D.

Comment: @Grubsnik: Why the focus on DLLs? It's in a separate _project_, not solution (by your own words), so I assume a project reference is being made. What does it matter if the project DLLs are separate or lumped together? This has no bearing on the code aspect.